# Why is my approach to calculate minimum number of steps to remove some random elements from a 2D array wrong?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array, in which are placed some n identical elements, say Xs, at random positions. Given the condition that I can remove all such Xs either by removing an entire row or column in a single step, I have to calculate the minimum number of steps required to remove all such Xs. As an example, I can remove Xs at position **(0,0), (1,0) and (0,1) in 2 steps, for a 2x2 array [1 for (0,0), (0,1) and 1 for (1,0)]**

I myself have come up with an approach- I am storing up the x and y co-ordinates in two separate arrays, and then counting the distinct co-ordinates in both. Comparing both of them, the one with the minimum distinct elements, is the answer, i.e., it is the minimum number of steps required.

I have checked this for a number of different inputs, and my answer seems to be correct every time. However, my instructor says this answer is wrong, though he wouldn't explain why. All he says is that it fails for a particular test case, but he won't mention it.

Therefore, I am asking for help. If you can find the failure with this approach, please tell me, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your

> I am storing up the x and y co-ordinates in two separate arrays, and
>   then counting the distinct co-ordinates in both.  Comparing both of
>   them, the one with the minimum distinct elements, is the answer, i.e.,
>   it is the minimum number of steps required.

algorithm correctly, then one simple counterexample is:

```
  [[1, 1, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]]
```

You'll have three distinct x coordinates and three distinct y coordinates where a `1` is located, but clearly it only takes two removal operations.

Comment: Wow. I guess I didn't see that since I'm new to programming. Do you have a better method? I'd really appreciate it if you could just give me a clue. Thanks, anyways!